# Tab Bar Image Resizing and Color

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a tab bar (5 buttons on the bottom that switches between views). I put an image there using

```
Image("TabGarden")
    .resizable()
```

But the icon is still huge. How do I shrink it to 24 x 24?

Also, for the color of the bottom tab, I tried doing this

```
init() {
    UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
}
```

But for one tab, the blue gets significantly darker. It's probably because of some appearance setting for that tab that makes it darker. How do I fix this?

Comment: You can just add a frame. `.frame(width: 24, height: 24, alignment: .center)`

Comment: @LeoDabus, not this time. Jason, TabView bar does not resize raster images (actually any images), you have to do that in advance, either (probably preferable) in Assets or programmatically in code.